# python: find specific word using regex

Tags: python, regex

**This is my string:**

> one time password for your transaction at, 'xxxx' of inr '1897.00' on your xxxx bank 'debit/credit/deposit/....' card ending '0000' is 0000"

`xxxx` - string, `0000` - numbers

I want to fetch all values in single quotes(')

**this is what I have tried:**

`[a-z ]+, ([a-z]+)[a-z ]+([0-9\.]+)` till here it is correct

**now i want to fetch (debit/credit/...), I am doing:**

> on your `[a-z]+` bank `[a-z]+[a-z ]+([0-9]+)[a-z ]+[0-9]`

What should be the better way?

Comment: [Reference - What does this regex mean](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937618/reference-what-does-this-regex-mean)?

Comment: Please format the question with code indentation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The safest and most performant way to do this is to match anything between two single quotes that is not a single quote (greedy or lazy does not matter in this case):

```
'[^']*'
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/VlocQ2/1)

Code sample:

```
import re    
regex = r"'[^']*'"    
test_str = '''one time password for your transaction at, 'xxxx' of inr '1897.00' \
on your xxxx bank 'debit/credit/deposit/....' card ending '0000' is 0000'''
matches = re.finditer(regex, test_str)
for match in matches:
    print ("Match was found at {start}-{end}: {match}".format(start = match.start(), end = match.end(), match = match.group()))
```

Answer (score 0):

The regex you are looking for is simply `r"'(.*?)'"`. An example program below:

```
import re

regex = r"'(.*?)'"

test_str = "\"one time password for your transaction at, 'xxxx' of inr '1897.00' on your xxxx bank 'debit/credit/deposit/....' card ending '0000' is 0000\""

matches = re.finditer(regex, test_str)

for matchNum, match in enumerate(matches):
    print ("Match {matchNum} was found at {start}-{end}: {match}".format(matchNum = matchNum, start = match.start(), end = match.end(), match = match.group()))
```

Which outputs:

```
Match 0 was found at 44-50: 'xxxx'
Match 1 was found at 58-67: '1897.00'
Match 2 was found at 86-113: 'debit/credit/deposit/....'
Match 3 was found at 126-132: '0000'
```

Learn more about using regex here: https://regex101.com/

Answer (score 0):

If you want all the characters in the single quotes,

```
import re
string = "'xxxx' of inr '1897.00' on your xxxx bank 'debit/credit/deposit/....' card ending '0000' is 0000"
all_matches = re.findall(r"\'.+?\'",string)
print all_matches
```